# How to Tell Rails to Have a Table with One Row

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

The situation:

I want to implement some general settings. The admin can specify say the canonical url, the site name, the description of their site (for meta description and so on). Some pretty basic configuration on their end.

My idea is to create a general settings table. Inside this table it will be seeded with one row. I allow the user to edit the row, not to be able to delete it or make a new one.

Is there a way to tell Rails that a table is to have only one row instead of playing hackery?

Comment: I don't get your point. If the user can only edit, so he can't delete nor create, how could you have more than one row in the table?

Comment: @FabKremer, I don't get it either. Not sure I'd bother with a table for one row, config file?

Comment: How do you allow the user to edit and update the config file?

Comment: @FabKremer I want it to be explicit that it is to have one row and one row only. Always develop as if a psychopath is going to read your code and knows where you live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`acts_as_singleton` gem](https://github.com/stephencelis/acts_as_singleton) can take care of settings, no need to write it yourself.

You declare it like this:

```
class Settings < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_singleton
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Settings.instance.site_description = "whatever";
```